# read from file and write to another files according to different titles

Tags: java, io

i have a question about java read and write files. In the file i want to read there are four titles "this_is_table_med", "this_is_table_nts", "this_is_table_lehramt", "this_is_table_allg" which are followed by their contents. as in the picture:[image]
I would like to split them into 4 tables as there are acutually 4 tables with titles and contents. At the end i only get the table for "this_is_table_med" and "this_is_table_lehramt", not all 4 tables, can some one help?
My codes are like:

```java
File file = new File(inputFileName);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String st;
while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (st != null && st.equals("this_is_table_nts")) {
        File file_nts = new File(outputPath + "_nts_dropOut.csv");
        FileOutputStream fo_nts = new FileOutputStream(file_nts);
        BufferedWriter writer_nts = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fo_nts));
        st = br.readLine();
        while (st != null && !st.contains("this_is_table_")) {

            writer_nts.write(st);
            writer_nts.newLine();

            st = br.readLine();

        }
        writer_nts.flush();
        writer_nts.close();

    } else if (st != null && st.equals("this_is_table_med")) {
        System.out.println("  " + st.toString());
        File file_medizin = new File(outputPath + "_medizin_dropOut.csv");
        FileOutputStream fo_medizin = new FileOutputStream(file_medizin);
        BufferedWriter writer_medizin = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fo_medizin));
        st = br.readLine();
        while (st != null && !st.contains("this_is_table_")) {
            writer_medizin.write(st);
            writer_medizin.newLine();

            st = br.readLine();
        }
        writer_medizin.flush();
        writer_medizin.close();

    } else if (st != null && st.equals("this_is_table_allg")) {
        System.out.println("  " + st.toString());
        File file_allg = new File(outputPath + "_allg_dropOut.csv");
        FileOutputStream fo_allg = new FileOutputStream(file_allg);
        BufferedWriter writer_allg = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fo_allg));
        st = br.readLine();
        while (st != null && !st.contains("this_is_table_")) {

            writer_allg.write(st);
            writer_allg.newLine();
            st = br.readLine();

        }
        writer_allg.flush();
        writer_allg.close();


    } else if (st != null && st.equals("this_is_table_lehramt")) {
        System.out.println("  " + st.toString());
        File file_lehramt = new File(outputPath + "_lehramt_dropOut.csv");
        FileOutputStream fo_lehramt = new FileOutputStream(file_lehramt);
        BufferedWriter writer_lehramt = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fo_lehramt));
        st = br.readLine();
        while (st != null && !st.contains("this_is_table_")) {

            writer_lehramt.write(st);
            writer_lehramt.newLine();
            st = br.readLine();

        }
        writer_lehramt.flush();
        writer_lehramt.close();

    }
    br.close();
}
```

Updates: i think the reason it jump over nts and allg is that: after the while-loop in the if loop for med (else if(st!=null&&st.equals("this_is_table_medizin")) "st" is equals to "this_is_table_nts". In the next step it comes to the outer while-loop "st" is the next line of "this_is_table_nts", what i need is to have st="this_is_table_nts" such that it comes to the if loop for nts.

Comment: If table "data" is always two lines , don't use while loops

Comment: i simplfy the table to make it readable, actually it has thousands of lines

Comment: Ultimately, I think you should rethink your code. 1) Don't use `br.readLine()` more than once (the very top loop). This is causing you to skip rows 2) Not all lines have `contains("this_is_table_")`, so any of those while loops will only run once, and only when you find a new table row, and you're ignoring any of the actual data for the tables with those loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using java 8 or higher, which I strongly assume you are, and the task here was not intended to get you to deal with `BufferedReader & BufferedWriter`, then I would recommend a different approach, which uses `Streams` and `java.nio.Files`. This way you can easily call methods for reading and writing and only have to worry about the grouping of your lines. Grouping is also easier thanks to streams. For this I use `AtomicInteger`, which I increment as soon as a line starts with `"this_is_table"`.

Assuming your inputfile is something like:

```
this_is_table_med 
V7_1,0.0,0.0,13.79
V7_TE,0.0,0.0,100
this_is_table_nts 
V8_1,0.0,0.0,13.79
V8_1,0.0,0.0,100
this_is_table_lehramt 
V38_1,0.0,0.0,100
V38_TE,0.0,0.0,100
this_is_table_allg
V8_2,0.0,0.0,13.79
V8_2,0.0,0.0,13.79
```

and is located at `fileName` the folowing snippet will create 4 files (`allg_dropOut.csv`, `lehramt _dropOut.csv`, `med _dropOut.csv`, `nts _dropOut.csv`) in the `outputPath` directory

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Miaomiao\\Documents\\mydata.csv"; 
        String outputPath = "C:\\Users\\Miaomiao\\Documents\\dir1\\";
        String suffix = "_dropOut.csv";

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

            stream.collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy( line -> isStartOfNewTable(line)? 
                                                   counter.incrementAndGet(): 
                                                   counter.get()))
                    .values().forEach(list -> {
                        String table = list.get(0); 
                        Path path = Paths.get(outputPath + 
                                              table.substring(table.lastIndexOf('_') + 1) +
                                              suffix);
                        try {
                            Files.write(path, list, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                             ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static boolean isStartOfNewTable (String str){
        return str.startsWith("this_is_table");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Few issues

1. You're reading mulitple lines at a time from the file. Leave the while loop alone. And this way, `st = br.readLine()` will never be null, so you don't need to check it
2. `st` will only equal a table name a handful of times, so you shouldn't check it everytime through the loop

Following code untested, but shows the general idea

- branch the code between "this_is_table" lines and those without. Use a list to save data while you read it rather than immediately write to a file
- when you find a *new* "this_is_table" line, then save off all previous lines (the list) to a file

```
  File file = new File(inputFileName);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  String tableName = null;
  String lastTable = null;
  List<String> tableData = new ArrayList<>();

  String st;
  while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
      if (st.startsWith("this_is_table_") {  // found start of a table
           // if previous table is known, then save it, e.g. write to a file here
           // condition needed for first table in file
           if (lastTable != null) {           
               String outputFile = tableName.substring("this_is_table".length()) + "_dropOut.csv";
               File out = new File(outputPath, outputFile);
               try(PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out)) {
                   for (String line : tableData) {
                     ps.println(line);
                   }
               } catch (Exception e) { System.err.println(e); }
               
               // start collecting data for a new table
               tableData = new ArrayList<>();
               lastTable = tableName;
           }

           tableName = st;
      } else {
          if (tableName != null) {
              // currently reading data for 'tableName'
              tableData.add(st);
          }
      }
  }
```